# Impedance in terms of position in a driven, open standing wave tube at resonance

Tags: acoustics

I have a cylindrical tube of length $L$ and radius $a$ with a loudspeaker sealed at one end ($x=0$) and open to the atmosphere at the other end ($x=L$). The tube is being driven by the speaker at a resonant frequency, $w_0$.

From *Fundamentals of Acoustics 4th Edition (Kinsler et al.)* chapter 10.4, the impedance at the open end $Z_{mL}$ should match the radiation impedance so that 
$\frac{Z_{mL}}{p_0cS} = \frac{1}{4}(ka)^2 + j 0.6 ka$ for an unflanged opening, where $S$ is the cross sectional area, $k$ is the wavenumber and $c$ is the speed of sound, including an end-correction of $L_{effective} = L + 0.6a$.

Now I would like to find the acoustic impedance at all other points along the tube, but I'm not sure where to start. I believe the wave in the pipe should be of the form: $p = Ae^{j(wt+kx)} + Be^{j(wt-kx)}$ where $p$ is the complex acoustic pressure and from this I have $Z_{mL} = \frac{p_oc}{S}\frac{Ae^{jkx}+Be^{-jkx}}{Ae^{jkx}-Be^{-jkx}}$. So from here I could use the radiation impedance at $x=L$ to eliminate either $A$ or $B$. However, I don't know how to calculate the impedance at the speaker end. My questions are:

1. Has my approach thus far been correct?
2. How do I work out the impedance at $x=0$ at the speaker end, or is there an easier way to include the boundary conditions at this end?
3. Since I'm only considering resonant frequencies $w_0$, is there an easier way to do this?